# Is it possible to solve the following 3 equations using matrices?

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

Is it possible to solve the following 3 equations using matrices?

$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$

$(x-2)^2 + (y-6)^2 = r^2$

$(x-8)^2 + (y-4)^2 = r^2$

I am attempting to find the equation of a circle given 3 coordinates. And whilst there are easier and quicker methods, I wasn't sure as to whether you could solve them using matrices?

Comment: It seems you want to compute the intersection between 3 circles, not the equation of a circle ? Also, is it a linear system ?

Comment: I'm trying to solve for x, y, and r.

Comment: @Somebody Related: [Determine if 3 circles intersect at a common point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2172339/determine-if-3-circles-intersect-at-a-common-point/).

Comment: You cannot solve it strictly using matrices because except for degenerate cases where two circles are tangent, there will be either $0$ or $2$ solution points. But matrix systems will either have $0, 1$ or infinitely many solutions. $2$ is not a possibility. In general, you will have to take at least one square root to solve the system. As Lelouch has shown, You can easily reduce it to two linear and one quadratic equation, which can be solved with a single application of the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 1):

At first sight, it seems this system is not linear (because both $x^2$ and $x$ are involved. If we had only $x^2$ then it would be linear in $x^2$ which would be fine) and that we cannot use a matrix method to solve it (since matrix means we are in a linear context). However, it is possible to cancel the non linear terms in this system (replace $x_1, y_1$ ... by your constants) :

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\left(x-x_{1}\right)^{2}+\left(y-y_{1}\right)^{2}=r_{}^{2} \\
&\left(x-x_{2}\right)^{2}+\left(y-y_{2}\right)^{2}=r_{}^{2} \\
&\left(x-x_{3}\right)^{2}+\left(y-y_{3}\right)^{2}=r_{}^{2}
\end{aligned}
$$
Expanding the squares give:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&x^{2}-2 x_{1} x+x_{1}^{2}+y^{2}-2 y_{1} y+y_{1}^{2}=r_{}^{2} \\
&x^{2}-2 x_{2} x+x_{2}^{2}+y^{2}-2 y_{2} y+y_{2}^{2}=r_{}^{2} \\
&x^{2}-2 x_{3} x+x_{3}^{2}+y^{2}-2 y_{3} y+y_{3}^{2}=r_{}^{2}
\end{aligned}
$$
We subtract the second equation from the first :
$$
\left(-2 x_{1}+2 x_{2}\right) x+\left(-2 y_{1}+2 y_{2}\right) y=-x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}-y_{1}^{2}+y_{2}^{2} .
$$
We subtract the third equation from the second :
$$
\left(-2 x_{2}+2 x_{3}\right) x+\left(-2 y_{2}+2 y_{3}\right) y=-x_{2}^{2}+x_{3}^{2}-y_{2}^{2}+y_{3}^{2} .
$$
These two equations are a 2x2 linear in $x$ and $y$ system which can be solved using matrix if you want. Then you can simply plug-in the solutions in one of the original equation to find r.